# AngularJS timer code won't go through all if else conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

I got problem of if else condition. I design a timer to show different messages on console in four conditions;however, the messages only show top two messages on console. it won't go to third and fourth. What is the problem of it ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        myApp.controller('TimeCtrl', ['$scope' , '$timeout', function ($scope , $timeout) {
            $scope.today = new Date();

            $scope.seconds = 0;
            $scope.max = 10;
            var stopped; 

            $scope.stopTimer = function(){
                $timeout.cancel(timer);

            };
            $scope.start = function(){

                timer = $timeout(function(){
                    $scope.seconds++;
                    console.log($scope.seconds);
                    if ($scope.seconds < 20) {
                        $scope.start();
                            if ( $scope.seconds < 5) {
                                //blue
                                console.log('progress-info');
                            }else if ( 5 <= $scope.seconds < 10 ) {
                                //green
                                console.log('progress-success');
                            }else if (  10 <= $scope.seconds < 15 ) {
                                //yellow
                                console.log('progress-warning');
                            }else if ( 15 <= $scope.seconds < 20){
                                //red
                                console.log('progress-danger'); 
                            };
                    }else{
                        $scope.stopTimer();
                    }

                },1000)

            }; 

        }]);

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TimeCtrl">
    <button ng-click="start()">start</button>
    <button ng-click="stopTimer()">stop</button>
        current time {{seconds}}
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: try to use just `if` statements instead of `if else`

Comment: your recursion loop looks like it's completely messed up to me; I'm surprised that any of these conditions trigger successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
else if ( 5 <= $scope.seconds < 10 )
```

The way javascript will test this is first if 5 <= seconds.  If true, the condition is true and the next evaluation is

```
true < 10
```

javascript treats true as 1 in this case, so this will evaluate to true, and the if block will be executed.

So, you expect that if $scope.seconds = 11, then this statement won't be true, but:

5 <= 11 -> true -> 1, then 1 < 10 -> true, so the block executes

To fix, change your if statement(s) to:

```
if(5 <= $scope.seconds && $scope.seconds < 10)
```

Also, of note, your variable "timer" isn't declared with "var", so you're essentially setting window.timer - not advisable.

```
myApp.controller('TimeCtrl', ['$scope' , '$timeout', function ($scope , $timeout) {
        $scope.today = new Date();

        $scope.seconds = 0;
        $scope.max = 10;
        var stopped; 
        var timer;  //declare timer so it won't be global

        $scope.stopTimer = function(){
            $timeout.cancel(timer);

        };
        $scope.start = function(){

            timer = $timeout(function(){
                $scope.seconds++;
                console.log($scope.seconds);
                if ($scope.seconds < 20) {
                    $scope.start();
                        if ( $scope.seconds < 5) {
                            //blue
                            console.log('progress-info');
                        }else if ( 5 <= $scope.seconds < 10 ) {
                            //green
                            console.log('progress-success');
                        }else if (  10 <= $scope.seconds < 15 ) {
                            //yellow
                            console.log('progress-warning');
                        }else if ( 15 <= $scope.seconds < 20){
                            //red
                            console.log('progress-danger'); 
                        };
                }else{
                    $scope.stopTimer();
                }

            },1000)

        }; 

    }]);
```